# Different result in view and stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My table structure like this

[image]

I am create view for this table

> SELECT  Entered FROM  dbo.tbPatientReport

In the table data like this

[image]

If i execute  view from sql query then it will give output like

> select  Entered from view_abc

[image]

**Desired Output**

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: What's wrong with output? You expected a different format or what?

Comment: I want output like table data.but it will give me output like view data

Comment: I got link [Date and Time function](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx) for the date and time conversion In this link all the date and time function available

Answer (score 2):

You should format date as you want in result.
e.g.

```
SELECT FORMAT( Entered,'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt','en-US') AS 'US'
```

FORMAT is one of the new built-in String Function introduced as a Part of Sql Server 2012. It returns the value formatted in the specified format using the optional culture parameter value. It is not an Sql Server native function instead it is .NET CLR dependent function.

> SYNTAX: FORMAT ( value, format [, culture ] )

**Edit**
Can you test this will be working.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), SYSDATETIME(), 22)

Format: MM/DD/YY HH:MI:SS AM
Output: 10/25/13 2:21:00 PM
```

Only problem is you cannot get FullYear.

Comment: 'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name. in SQL 2008 and he want that format in SQL 2008

Comment: But i am using SQL 2008

Comment: Try above given string will give you output as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your [Entered] column [Datetime] in your table structure does not allow nulls, it's not ticked.

What version of SQL Management Studio are you using? And are you selecting the data in a plain select query or are you choosing to View the data?
In older versions "View" opens the edit window with your code on top.

While in the editing view the last row will always be NULL as it is expecting new data.